# SQL sorting month end (mmm-yy) starting with April

Tags: sql, date

In SQL I am trying to convert dates to `mmm-yy` and then sort starting with April as the first month.  So far I have managed to converted the date to `mmm-yy` using

```
SELECT  
    LNAME as Location,
    SUBSTRING( CONVERT( VARCHAR(11), MonthEnd, 113), 4, 8) AS [MonthEnd],
    CAST (TYPEDESC as VARCHAR(20)) as 'Factory',
    Sum(Tonnes) as Tonnes
FROM (
    SELECT          
        EOMONTH(X_DELIVERY_DATE) as MonthEnd,
        ...
```

but I cannot complete the final step, all I get is the date sorted alphabetically.  If someone could please help!!

Comment: Tip: Never convert date values to strings, especially not in SQL for this reason. If you need to group-by months then convert the date values to use the same date value to represent each month.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results? Your question is way more ambiguous than you might think.  For instance, do you want Aprils from all years to appear together or separately.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you use SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    MonthEnd DATETIME
)

INSERT @Temp VALUES
('2015/01/01'),
('2015/02/01'),
('2015/03/01'),
('2015/04/01'),
('2015/05/01'),
('2015/06/01'),
('2015/07/01'),
('2015/08/01'),
('2015/09/01'),
('2015/10/01'),
('2015/11/01'),
('2015/12/01'),
('2016/01/01'),
('2016/02/01'),
('2016/03/01'),
('2016/04/01'),
('2016/05/01'),
('2016/06/01'),
('2016/07/01'),
('2016/08/01'),
('2016/09/01'),
('2016/10/01'),
('2016/11/01'),
('2016/12/01')

SELECT MonthEnd, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), MonthEnd, 113), 4, 8)
FROM @Temp
ORDER BY YEAR(MonthEnd), (MONTH(MonthEnd) + 8) % 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the DATEPART function

```
DATEPART(month, '10/5/2015')
```

And try this calculation:

```
SELECT (DATEPART(year, '3/5/2015') * 100) +
       (CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, '3/5/2015') > 3 
       THEN DATEPART(month, '3/5/2015') - 4 
       ELSE DATEPART(month, '3/5/2015') + 9 
END);
```